# How to use a pickle file for Spacy NER model training?

Tags: python, nlp, pickle, spacy

I have data for fine-tuning in this format:

```
[[(('Kaweah', 'NNP'), 'O'),
  (('Delta', 'NNP'), 'O'),
  (('Mental', 'NNP'), 'O'),
  (('Health', 'NNP'), 'O'),
  (('Hospital', 'NNP'), 'O'),
  (('D/p', 'NNP'), 'O'),
  (('Aph', 'NNP'), 'O'),
  (('is', 'VBZ'), 'O'),
  (('located', 'VBN'), 'O'),
  (('at', 'IN'), 'O'),
  (('1100', 'CD'), 'B-GPE'),
  (('SO', 'NNP'), 'I-GPE'),
  (('.', '.'), 'I-GPE'),
  (('AKERS', 'NNP'), 'I-GPE'),
  (('STREET', 'NNP'), 'I-GPE')],
 [(('CHARLTON', 'NNP'), 'O'),
  (('MEMORIAL', 'NNP'), 'O'),
  (('HOSPITAL', 'NNP'), 'O'),
  (('is', 'VBZ'), 'O'),
  (('located', 'VBN'), 'O'),
  (('at', 'IN'), 'O'),
  (('2449', 'CD'), 'B-GPE'),
  (('THIRD', 'NNP'), 'I-GPE'),
  (('STREET', 'NNP'), 'I-GPE'),
  ((',', ','), 'I-GPE'),
  (('GA', 'NNP'), 'I-GPE')]]
```

But spacy training format is looking like this:

```
TRAIN_DATA =[ ("Pizza is a common fast food.", {"entities": [(0, 5, "FOOD")]}),
              ("Pasta is an italian recipe", {"entities": [(0, 5, "FOOD")]}) ]
```

What should I do to convert my pickle file to the spacy format?

Answer (score 0):

You can just take each token and concatenate whitespace on them to get the text input and then calculate the start and stop for the spans of each entity label.

*but* you will be creating **artificial training data** since you don't know what whitespace was used around each token. That information is lost in CoNLL format.

Therefore, the NER model you train **will not be robust** since it doesn't know how to label tokens as *it will learn to always expect the whitespace concatenation of your choice*.

Basically, **can't be done**, you lost information in CoNLL format which cant be recuperated.